# Link Juice Prioritize www. and domain name

Tags: seo, robots.txt, no-www

Our company ran a site audit on a very basic one-page website and is receiving this warning.

> "Normally, a webpage can be accessed with or without adding www.to its
>   domain name. If you haven't specified which version should be
>   prioritized, search engines will crawl both versions, and the link
>   juice will be split between them. Therefore, none of your page
>   versions will get high positions in search results."

I know very little on this topic but want to know what I can do to the HTML so  the "Link Juice" is not spread between www. and the domain name and so the message will not appear anymore. Do I need to add a robots.txt file to the root directory?

Site Structure

```
index.html
/images folder
```

Possibly relevant head info?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
```

Comment: No need to downvote. An OP (which may look stupid) showed an attempt to solve the problem (unsuccessfully).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any or all of following methods.
A. Add canonical link to head section of each page using either `www` or `non-www` version (your preferable). Note that crawlers also distinguish `http:` and `https:`

```
<link href="http://www.domain.com/about-us.html" rel="canonical" />
```

B. Add `Link` header to HTTP response.

```
Link: <http://www.domain.com/about-us.html>; rel="canonical"
```

C. Redirect permanently `301 - moved permanently` to your preferable version. If you use IIS you can add this rule from IIS Management Console (URL Rewrite tool).

`<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />` is default value and can be removed. `robots.txt` is the must.

Comment: Alex thanks for this. I ended up using an htaccess file with 301 redirect for a non-www condition. It worked for me. Do you see any issues with this technique compared to what you came up with.

Comment: Canonical meta tag is also highly recommended. Don't forget `sitemap.xml` as well.